# D3 Types in NextJS React

Tags: typescript, d3.js, next.js, typeerror

Why are my types not working here? I'm following this guide:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-d3.js-inside-a-react-app
to make d3 work within React. I'm using Nextjs to do this and can't figure out why it's not picking up my types. If this answer is obvious, could you also accompany it with a link to reference?

Thanks.

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

export const useD3 = (renderChartFn, dependencies: Array<any>) => {
    const ref = React.useRef();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        renderChartFn(d3.select(ref.current));
        return () => {};
      }, dependencies);
    return ref;
}
```

```html
{
  "name": "_",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^7.6.1",
    "next": "12.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/d3-selection": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/node": "18.6.5",
    "@types/react": "18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.4",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you trying to solve? What is the problem? It looks like you have "strict": true or "noImplicitAny": true in your `tsconfig`, which means you cannot have an implicit any. Your params must be typed. Even if it's an explicit any, as in `renderChartFn: any`.

Comment: So do I have to manually type over the d3 generics to make this work?

Comment: I'm confused, where are you expecting types to come from? Do you have a separate type declaration file or something? This looks like a hook you're writing from scratch. Yes, you have to satisfy the typescript constraints of the environment you're working in for TS to compile. Feel free to take shortcuts though, it's one of the great things about TS. Also, I remember using react-d3 (I know you're not using it) but recall it being annoying to type.